# Laravel Auth change table name

Tags: php, database, laravel, authentication, model

So I have generated Laravel's authentication code using

```
php artisan make:auth
```

But I'd like to change the table name in the database to accounts rather than users. I already changed it in the migrations, user model and config/auth.php but it still looks for 'users' table in the database when I try to register/login. I've searched for a solution, but that is all everyone is suggesting. (BTW I already have a table called 'users' that has other data in it)

Anything else I need to change?

Comment: Do you have any exceptions or error output to show? An exception trace would be helpful

Comment: Here's the output when I try to register for example: http://pastebin.com/PyEjUBhF

Comment: show us what u changed in auth.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like is the validation trying to check if the email exists in the users table.

Change your validation to this:

```
'email' => 'required|email|unique:accounts'
```